# Редактирование строк xml

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea

Есть строки в xml которые я вытягиваю в коде. в IntelliJ IDEA, когда открываешь файл с кодом, видно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а когда нажимаешь на текст - это превращается в обычный код

```
album.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.main_min_album) + text);
```

Вопрос #1: Как заставить этот когда свернуться в состояние как на картинке? (закрывать и открывать класс каждый раз надоело уже)

Вопрос #2: если ли способ редактировать эту строку в *xml из класса? Т.е. чтобы не открывать сам xml, искать нужную тебе строку. А нажал какую-то кнопку и ты можешь редактировать эту строку, не выходя из класса. (конечно, она изменится везде, где применяется эта строка)

Comment: всегда использую обычные ctr+лкм, все достаточно удобно и быстро.

Comment: @UjinUkr я не знал!) а не подскажите как свернуть строку?

Comment: поищите в hot key, думаю там что то есть

Comment: CTRL Numpad + / CTRL Numpad - (или в контекстом меню: Folding -> Collapse\Expand) - свернуть\развернуть подсказку